# Comment my off days training routine (boxing)

Tags: training, boxing

I'm a boxer training 3 times a week. I run for about 50 minutes on all other days and when I'm feeling fresh I also jump rope for between 15 and 30 minutes after running. During training there's a lot of push ups, quite some squats and a bit of crunches. It's not enough for me. Naturally I want to focus on the muscle groups most important for boxing: http://www.expertboxing.com/boxing-training/boxing-workouts/most-important-muscles-for-fighting

My weight is right for the class I compete in. I'm 5 ft 9 in and weigh a little over 165 lbs.

I do the following bodyweight exercises at home (I realized early on that I don't need weights because I'm a short stocky guy and develop muscles quickly without having to use any weights):

On one day I will focus on triceps and legs (2 exercises for each) with **pushups**, **dips**, **squats** and **lunges**.

The other day I focus on biceps, back and abs with **neutral grip pull ups**, **situps** and **some lower back exercises** from a lying facedown position. I sometimes also use my pullup bar to get into a dead hang position and then bring my knees up to a 90 degree angle or rotate both knees left and right so the crunches aren't the only exercise for abs.

Do the 2 workouts complement each other well? Are dips necessary when I'm also working my triceps all the time with push ups?